What is the distribution of error term in Gompertz AFT model?
Given the AFT model $\ln(T)=\beta+\sigma\times W$, the distribution of $T$ depends on the random term $W$. If $T$ follows a Gompertz distribution with the shape and rate, how can I derive the value of $\sigma$ and $\beta$ with the shape and rate? I guess at first I need to know the distribution of $W$.

While you wait for an answer, you might find some information in the eha package documentation and code. This vignette discusses the way that a Gompertz distribution needs to be parameterized for an AFT model to work, and how the AFT formulation works best if hazard is strictly increasing in time.
